# how to import git resources into the terraform module?

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to import git resource into module and getting an error.
command:

```
terraform import module.users.user_jons.git.github_membership[membership_jons] org:jonsh
```

error:

```
no matches found: module.users.user_jons.git.github_membership[membership_jons]
```

the structure:
[image]

provider.tf

```
provider "github" {
  token = "***"
  owner = "org"

}

module "users" {
  source = "./users/"
}
```

users.modules.tf

```
module "user_jons" {
    source = "./jons/"
}
```

jons.modules.tf

```
module "git" {
    source = "./git/"
}
```

git.member.tf

```
resource "github_membership" "membership_jons" {

}
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand the question, but it should probably be something like `terraform import module.user_jons.github_membership.membership_jons <organization:username>` where the `organization:username` needs to be populated with real values.

Comment: @MarkoE i'm using this command:
**terraform import module.users.user_jons.git.github_membership[membership_jons] org:jonsh** and getting error

Comment: Because it does not work the way you are trying to do it. Have you actually tried the example I gave? `terraform import module.user_jons.github_membership.membership_jons org:jonsh`?

Comment: @MarkoE, I do and get:
Import to non-existent module
Module user_jons is in the module users

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem by changing command to:

```
terraform import module.users.**module**.user_jons.**module**.git.github_membership.membership_jons org:jons
```

Problem was with wrong path to modules.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).